invaliddomainnamelabel: the domain name label siradmin is invalid. it must conform to the following regular expression: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$
As per the below error in azure pipeline..I have tried several alternatives to comply with required format for the admin user name on parameter.json file ..  but every time getting same error
error]invaliddomainnamelabel: the domain name label siradmin is invalid. it must conform to the following regular expression: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$. []
I have tried several alternatives to comply with required format for the admin user name on parameter.json file.. But no luck yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
